# How to create MP3 file using CSCore from WAV file or how to solve "No MP3-Encoder was found"

Tags: c#, mp3, wav, encode, cscore

I was wondering if it is possible to encode to mp3 after recording a wav file. I tried to change the WasapiCapture parameters but I think that is not working since the sound length has only 5 seconds and 1,20 MB.

Here the sample code trying to converting to mp3 before start the recording:

```
_soundIn = new WasapiCapture(false, AudioClientShareMode.Shared, 100,
                new WaveFormat(44100, 32, 2, AudioEncoding.MpegLayer3));
```

I tried to do as well as the example below but I always get this error: No MP3-Encoder was found.

http://cscore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/RecordToWma/Program.cs

Thank you guys!

Comment: That's why it doesn't work. I tried on Windows 7. I will use lame to convert a wav to mp3 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the MMF mp3 encoder requires Windows 8 (or Server 2012).

From MSDN:

Requirements

Minimum supported client
Windows 8 [desktop apps only]

Minimum supported server
Windows Server 2012 [desktop apps only]